# Tier Price and MSRP price

Tags: magento

I want to display both MSRP(Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price) Price and tier price in Product page of magento.

Both price should display at same time on product page in magento

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how you want to display it? Tier should show automatically within price.phtml - what have you tried? Do you have any code samples?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the following code in your theme/catalog/product/view.phtml where you want to show the MSRP Price.

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,false); ?>
```

Tier Price will be automatically shown within price.phtml